# Why I saw the content in my window 10 screen when booting ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia

When booting ubuntu, after I input my user name and password, before it show the Ubuntu desktop, I saw the content in my window 10 screen which I was working on before restart to switch to ubuntu. I am wondering why?

I am using ubuntu 18.04, Nvidia 1060, dual boot :ubuntu + win10(ssd)

```
cat /etc/os-release

NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Comment: I am not sure what exactly causes this, but I have seen it too.  It could be a "memory" in the HDMI cable.  I know that if there is too much electronic interference around HDMI cables it can cause unpredictable things to happen.  Try moving the cable away from power supplies, etc.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks for your advice!